# Application crashed when calling selectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my application I have an `UITableView` with dynamic number of rows. Once user click on a cell, the application navigates to another `UIView` and user can click the back button to go to the `UITableView`. When going back I wanted to highlight the selected cell and scroll the cell to the center. This is how I achieve it

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      if (!isScrollerSet && self.selectedRowNo!=-1) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedRowNo 
                                                        inSection:0];
            [self.tableViewP selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                                         animated:YES
                                   scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
            isScrollerSet = YES;       
      }
}
```

When the user comes back this method will be call when the rows are displayed again. I set the correct row number in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

When the `UITableView` has less numbers of rows this works fine. Lets say `UITableVIew` have 100 rows and user clicked on 90th row. When he comes back application crashed when calling the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. Exception is as follows

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
    reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds 
    for empty array'
```

Then I move this code to `viewDidAppear:`. Now it woks with with any number of rows. I cant figure out why this happen. Can some one explain what was the reason?

Comment: Problem is in your datasource which you provide to table, Check your datasource has data or not.

Comment: @iAmbitious  How it depend on the method where I try to select the cell (In willDisplayCell: or viewDidAppear:). Can you explain bit more.

Comment: Add break point to All exception.

Comment: Seems to be the object which populates your tableview is not available.

Comment: I checked the datasource array count. That array is not nil and has full amount of data when the exceptions occurred. I checked that by adding break point to all exception

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you do not have defective code it is possible that:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is called before your `Datasource` is initialized. For example, if your `UITableView` is instantiated in the `UIViewController's viewDidLoad` function, and then you initialize your `Datasource` afterwards then upon reloading the `UITableView` you will have a nil value.

Whereas `viewDidAppear` occurs later in the runtime than `viewDidLoad` so at that point your `Datasource` is valid and you're able to reference that index in the `NSArray`. If this is the cause of your exception then you would be able to solve it by doing your `Datasource` initializing at the very beginning of `viewDidLoad`.

This is my best guess based on the information you provided. You may want to give more detail in your question.

Comment: When user comes back I don't initialize the datasource array. It's already initialized in the init method. I checked the array size at the moment of crash occurred. It is fully loaded at that time.

Comment: If you are receiving the exception: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds for empty array'` and you're checking the size of the array at the point of the crash, and its showing greater than 3 then I think you have the wrong array. It would help people answer your question if you added some print statements to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

- tableView willDisplayCell
  method is called before your data is loaded.so deferentially it will show an error because it is not getting any index position because of no data in tableview

So the solution is that you can set an integer or any other variable and check it inside cellforRowAtindexpath. when you return back..(Better to store value in  UserDafault)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   ...
   if(indexpath.row==<your value>)
   {
     // your code.
   }
....
}
```

Comment: can you please provide me a reference to the 'tableView willDisplayCell method is called before your data is loaded'. Did Apple docs has such thing?